# Creation fails without clearing caches and cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and I'm facing issues in some creation functionalities. It was solved by clearing the browser's caches and cookies.

I want to know what may cause this failure and did this problem exist for these kind of projects?

Any insight related to this subject will be helpful.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what exactly problem do you have?

Comment: @GoodboY i would like to know what is the relation between caches & cookies and the failure of creation functions such as, creating user account

Comment: Maybe, the old version of your javascript code was cached. So, your app used this old version. When you cleared the cache, your app fetched the new version of your js code, which may contain some changes in the creation functions